# woocommerce - completed order email - don't send if it's recurring payment

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I have a subscription service running on WooCommerce, using the Subscriptio plugin and I don't want to send the renewal order emails. They are exactly the same as Completed Order emails.

What I am looking for is a hook/filter, something like `woocommerce_email_completed_order`, that would prevent the renewal email from being sent.

I am sure it's supereasy, but that hook/filter just escapes my Google searches! :)

Comment: which plugin are you use?

Comment: You need stop renewal email.am I right?

Comment: Thank you for your reaction! Yes, you're precisely correct! I am using Subscriptio plugin to extend WooCommerce. I had that hook once found, but I lost it somewhere :(

Comment: woocommerce_resend_order_emails_available

Comment: I am not sure this is it. After googling it, I found nothing that would help me solve my challenge.

Comment: \woocommerce\includes\emails\class-wc-email-customer-completed-order.php

and 

$available_emails = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_resend_order_emails_available', array( 'new_order', 'cancelled_order', 'customer_processing_order', 'customer_completed_order', 'customer_invoice', 'customer_refunded_order' ) );

Comment: Again, thank you for that, but I need to hook into something that is fired when the completed order email is sent. Then, I decide if the order is a renewal order, and if it is, I won't send the email. This is my train of thought.

Answer (score 0):

We figured out how to do this. You have to use `remove_action()` on `woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification` in the `woocommerce_email` action.

So for you, something like this:

```
// Conditionally remove action to send email
function unhook_emails($email_class) {

    // Check whether to send the renewal email or not
    $send_renewal_email = check_send_renewal_email();

    if (!$send_renewal_email) {

        // Remove action to prevent email from being sent
        remove_action(
            "woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification",
            array(
                $email_class->emails["WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order"],
                "trigger"
            )
        );
    }
}

add_action("woocommerce_email", "unhook_emails");
```

Hopefully that helps!