# WooCommerce should NOT send order complete mail when order is subscription parent

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to unsent the WooCommerce default order complete mail when a customer buys a subscription. WooCommerce creates a parent order for that subscription. When we close that parent order, the customer will get the order completed mail. Then we try no block but only on parent order for subscriptions.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47998631/3730754) but it's for renewal completed mails.

There is an info `order_type` which should store the info if it is a subscription parent order or not, how can that value be accessed?

There is maybe also a way to check via `wcs_order_contains_subscription()` if it is a parent subscription order. (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/order-cart-functions/)

Something like this: `wcs_order_contains_subscription( $order, $order_type )`

**Update:**
With the new information this is the current status:

```
// Conditionally remove action to send order completed email for subscription parent order

function unhook_order_complete_email_subscription_parent($email_class) {

    // Check whether to send the parent order completed email or not
    $send_parent_completed_email = order_type(parent);

    if (!$send_parent_completed_email) {

        // Remove action to prevent email from being sent
        remove_action(
            "woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification",
            array(
                $email_class->emails["WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order"],
                "trigger"
            )
        );
    }
}

add_action("woocommerce_order_status_changed", "unhook_order_complete_email_subscription_parent");
```

Comment: Maybe you are hooking a later function too late when the order details is lost. Hook to on order status change? Remove the action inside this hook https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705554/woocommerce-trigger-a-function-on-order-status-complete

Comment: So you mean the current code is right but just a function is too late?

Comment: Yes, you are looking to get order details so you can verify if it is a parent of or not. `woocommerce_email` will not pass order data, its not its business `woocommerce_order_status_changed` will pass `order_id` as its first parameter. So, yes, hook to `woocommerce_order_status_changed` instead, then run your `remove_action`

Comment: In tried that approach. See updated question. Think we are on the right way..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function like `order_type()`. This should fix your problem:

```
// Conditionally remove action to send order completed email for subscription parent order

function unhook_order_complete_email_subscription_parent($order_id) {
    $email_class = wc()->mailer()->get_emails();
    
    // Check whether to send the parent order completed email or not
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    if ($order && !$order->get_parent_id()) {
        // Remove action to prevent email from being sent
        remove_action(
            "woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification",
            array(
                $email_class->emails["WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order"],
                "trigger"
            )
        );
    }
}

add_action("woocommerce_order_status_changed", "unhook_order_complete_email_subscription_parent");
```

**EDIT:**

This is a better approach that works. `get_parent_id()` will return 0 if an order is a parent, else it will return the `parent_id` if it is a child.

```
function enable_email($order) {
    // We have to restore the configuration of what we disabled after we are done with our hack
    if ($order->get_parent_id() != 0 && ($status = get_transient( "tmp_completed_order_email" )) !== false) {
        wc()->mailer()->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order']->enabled = $status;        
    }
}

function disable_email($order)
{
    if ($order->get_parent_id() != 0) { // It is a child
        // Store the current configuration in a temporary place.
        $current_status = wc()->mailer()->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order']->enabled;

        // Everything should be done in 10 seconds. Lets keep the data till then
        set_transient( 'tmp_completed_order_email', $current_status, 10 );

        // Disabled completed order email
        wc()->mailer()->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order']->enabled = 'no';
    }
}
add_action("woocommerce_before_order_object_save", "disable_email");
add_action("woocommerce_after_order_object_save", "enable_email");
```

Comment: Does not work as wanted. The Order complete mail is also sended for parent subscription orders. Can it maybe be a hook priority problem?

Comment: Did you also use subscriptions? Becasue this code does not work on my system. I'm wondering if it is working on you side. :)

Comment: I was able to test the code on another system. There we have the same situation. Does this code work at your end? Happy to work with you on that :)

Comment: Sorry, was away. Yes, it is sending to parent only. Does it send to child as well?

Comment: Hello James, no problem :) Hmm I'm try to NOT send order complete mail for the parent order.

Comment: It is something with this "if ($order && !$order->get_parent_id())" But I do not understand how to check if it is a parent order or not.. If it is a parent sub order.. then unhook otherwise do nothing.

Comment: Thanks. I made a few tests. But the parent order completed mail are still sendet to the customer. So something is not working as it should in our system. The code above is fully working on your end?

Comment: Yes, are you using any extra plugins for this order management? Subscriptions?

Comment: We use WooCommerce Subscription plugin and we want, that no order completed mail would be send, if the order is marked as a subscription parent order.

Comment: The problem is here somewhere. "if ($order->get_parent_id() != 0) { // It is a child" The check should be if it is a parent or not and if yes, then unhook. But when the order is a parent, then the get_parent_id() !=0 does not work. I tried to use NULL but that does also not work :(

Comment: If you do not want to sent to parent, change `!=` to `==`. A `get_parent_id() == 0` means it is parent

Comment: I see. In the code we have two functions with that part. (function disable_email and function enable_email). But I have problems with taht. If I use this then all other order complete mails are not send. I guess I have to work with wcs_order_contains_subscription() and check for $order_type = 'parent'

Comment: the check on the parent order ID does not work for us. I found out, that our multivendor plugin also use the same field when child order are created. so then those mails are also not send. Do you see a way to do it via $order_type = 'parent'?